# How can i get each child? Firebase getValue [android]

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How could i get all the childs from my database?

This code get the first Element, how can i get Element_2,3 and successive? The best i accomplised is serialize the first country and print it.

**My Database:**

```
     {
    "Capitals" : {
     "Country_1" : {
     "Country" : "Macedonia",
     "Capital" : "Skopje"   
     },
    "Country_2" : {
    "Country" : "Madagascar",
    "Capital" : "Antananarivo"      
    },
    "Country_3" : {
    "Country" : "Malawi",
    "Capital" : "Lilongwe"
    }
    }
```

**My Code**

```
@Override
public void onStart(){
  super.onStart();
    final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference capitalsRef = database.getReference("Capitals");
    compresoresRef.orderByChild("Ref").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        countryModel cm = dataSnapshot.getValue(countryModel.class);
        String country = cm.getCountry();
        String capital= cm.getCapital();
        textData1.setText(country);
        textData2.setText(capital);
    }

     @Override
     public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

     }

     @Override
     public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
     }

     @Override
     public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

     }

    @Override
     public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
      });
```

The **dataSnapshot** while executing looks like:

```
DataSnapshot { key =Country_1, value = {Country=Macedonia, Capital=Skopje} }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use an `ArrayList` for store all childs that you get from Firebase using `addChildEventListener`

```
ArrayList<countryModel> countryList = new ArrayList<countryModel)();
compresoresRef.orderByChild("Ref").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
         countryModel cm = dataSnapshot.getValue(countryModel.class);
         countryList.add(cm);
         ...
    }
}
```

**Or if** you use `addValueEventListener` for retrieve data, it will look like

```
compresoresRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        countryList.clear();
        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
            countryModel cm = postSnapshot.getValue(countryModel.class);
            countryList.add(cm);
        }
    }

    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
        System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
       for(DataSnapshot post:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
         {
       countryModel countryModel cm = post.getValue(countryModel.class);
       }
    }
```